# chartist js point animation

Tags: html, charts, chartist.js

I did a chart with chartist.js and i replaced the points with circles so i can add outline like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/gLnkwLj0/). Now i would like to have an animation for the points, but it is not working.

Here is the code:

```
seq = 0, delays = 80, duration = 600;
chart.on('draw', function(data) {
      if(data.type === 'line' || data.type === 'area') {
        data.element.animate({
          d: {
            begin: 600,
            dur: 700,
            from: data.path.clone().scale(1, 0).translate(0, data.chartRect.height()).stringify(),
            to: data.path.clone().stringify(),
            easing: Chartist.Svg.Easing.easeOutQuint
          }
        });
      } else if(data.type === 'circle') {
            seq++;
            data.element.animate({
              opacity: {
                begin: seq * delays,
                dur: durations,
                from: 0,
                to: 1,
                easing: 'ease'
              }
            });
        }
    });

    seq = 0;
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Please explain how it is not working, this will help viewers more.

Comment: data.type must be 'point', and you are using "durations" but declaring "duration"